# How can I customize 404 in IHP?

Tags: haskell, ihp

I could not find an obvious way to handle general 404 pages in IHP.

Is there a simple way to override the default "Not Found" route on invalid pages in FrontController or Router?

Comment: Given this issue https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/367, I’d assume the answer is: currently, no.

Comment: Yes, there has been some work on that issue in the past. Here's the direction how we wan this to work: https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/pull/423#issuecomment-700843156 Hopefully makes it into the next IHP release. Will then submit a answer to this SO question :)

Answer (score 4):

There's now an easy way to add a custom 404 page by creating a file at static/404.html. Then IHP will render that HTML file instead of displaying the default IHP not found page.

[Check the documentation for more details.](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/routing.html#custom-404-page)

(added this just in case someone get's here via google)